# The modulo in RPG 4?

Tags: websphere, ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

Anyone know how I could do a modulo, please in RPG IV?

I tried `%2 = 0` but it's not exact!

If you have a solution, I'm interested.

```
dcl-s slash        varchar(20);
dcl-s antiSlash    varchar(20);
dcl-s i            packed(3:0);
dcl-s j            packed(3:0);
dcl-s k            packed(3:0);
dcl-s message      varchar(20);
dcl-s waitInput    char(1);

FOR i = 1 by 1 to 10;
  slash += '/';
ENDFOR;

FOR j = 1 by 1 to 10;
  antiSlash += '\';
ENDFOR;


FOR k = 1 by 1 to 6;

  IF k % 2 = 0;
      message = %char(slash);
      dsply message ' ' waitInput;
  ENDIF;

ENDFOR;

*INLR = *on;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=operations-arithmetic)

```
                    Tradition Fix-format    Free Format Syntax
Division Remainder  MVR (Move Remainder)    %REM (Return Integer Remainder)
```

So for your code...
`if %rem(k:2) = 0;`